# Invalid collection reference Collection references must have an odd number of segments

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently encountering this problem in my react native app using Firebase when im trying to update the document to firestore.
This is all problem log:

> Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but Posts/6ePmGkmxgQkq1PT0q3Yt has 2.

!Here is my code:

[image]

the "idPost" is the id of the document.

I hope you guys can help me solve this problem, thank you in advanced

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to [**update** a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9_9), the API call to make is `updateDoc` and not `addDoc` (which adds a document to a collection).

Comment: I tried and it works, I'm new with firebase, so I thought the syntax was the same and if the document existed it would overwrite it. Anyway, thank u so much for helping me. Have a good day, sir ❤️